# How would I validate the value from JSON api and convert it into another word in react.js?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, type-conversion

Here is my JSON file from API

[image]

From the above picture, my status is return in **int** to represent the result of status. Status 1 mean it is **approve**

So here is how I get my api data react.js

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const users_id = localStorage.getItem('id');

    fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/purchase-order/list/${users_id}`,)
     .then((resp)=>{
       resp.json().then((res)=>{
           console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({data: res.data});
       })
     })
   }

render(){
    const data = this.state.data
    return (
      <div>
       <Header />
       {/* <NavigationBar /> */}
        <div>
        { Object.keys(data).map((key) => <h1>Status:{data[key].status}</h1>) }
         //Here show the status in number, but I need to show the "Approve" on here instead of 1
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is it any solution or method that can help to validate the result status , and show the real meaning word in the UI page?

There are still have some of the status here
1 is Approve
2 is Pending
3 is Rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assign the numbers to an array

A simple solutions could be to use the numbers as index and print a word on that

```
const statusAry = ['broken', 'good', 'incomplete'];

...

{ Object.keys(data).map((key) => <h1>Status:{statusAry[data[key].status]}</h1>) }
```

Comment: Cool!!, by using this way can show the status word! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
{ Object.keys(data).map((key) => <h1>Status:{data[key].status === 1 ? 'Approved' : 'Rejected'}</h1>) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

Define your status

[image]

And use it like that :

{Status[data[key].status]}